# Jooq binding for "timestamp with time zone" type in postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8, jooq, java-time

[Jooq currently does not support JSR 310 types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749317/829571) and [support will not come until v3.8](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2738).

Using simple converters generally works, except for certain types, such as postgres' `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, which requires a custom binding. So I have tried to write one but the generated `XxxRecord` classes still use a `Timestamp` data type for the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` fields in my DB.

**What do I need to change in my code below to see postgres' `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as an `Instant`in jooq's generated classes?**

#### Converter

```
public class TimestampConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, Instant> {
  @Override public Instant from(Timestamp ts) {
    return ts == null ? null : ts.toInstant();
  }
  @Override public Timestamp to(Instant instant) {
    return instant == null ? null : Timestamp.from(instant);
  }
  @Override public Class<Timestamp> fromType() { return Timestamp.class; }
  @Override public Class<Instant> toType() { return Instant.class; }
}
```

#### Custom binding

```
public class TimestampBinding implements Binding<Timestamp, Instant> {

  private static final Converter<Timestamp, Instant> converter = new TimestampConverter();

  private final DefaultBinding<Timestamp, Instant> delegate = 
                                                       new DefaultBinding<> (converter());

  @Override public Converter<Timestamp, Instant> converter() { return converter; }

  @Override public void sql(BindingSQLContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
    delegate.sql(ctx);
  }

  //etc. same for all other overriden methods.
}
```

#### pom.xml (extracts)

```
<customType>
  <name>java.time.Instant</name>
  <type>java.time.Instant</type>
  <binding>xxx.TimestampBinding</binding>
</customType>

...

<forcedType>
  <name>java.time.Instant</name>
  <types>timestamp with time zone</types>
</forcedType>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to escape the spaces in `<types>` with backslashes, as follows:

```
<types>timestamp\ with\ time\ zone</types>
```

You can't just have regular spaces in `<types>` because by default, `org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase` will [parse regular expressions in COMMENTS mode](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.7.0/jOOQ-meta/src/main/java/org/jooq/util/AbstractDatabase.java#L248) which makes the created `Pattern` object [ignore whitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) in your regex.  You could also do something like `<types>timestamp.*zone</types>`, or specify your own [`<regexFlags>`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.7.0/jOOQ-meta/src/main/resources/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.7.0.xsd#L364).

The following is the full Maven `jooq-codegen-maven` plugin tag that works for me.  I also found the `<binding>` to be unnecessary.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>

        <jdbc>
            <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql:postgres</url>
            <user>postgres</user>
            <password>mypass</password>
        </jdbc>

        <generator>
            <database>
                <customTypes>
                    <customType>
                        <name>Instant</name>
                        <type>java.time.Instant</type>
                        <converter>xxx.TimestampConverter</converter>
                    </customType>
                </customTypes>

                <forcedTypes>
                    <forcedType>
                        <name>Instant</name>
                        <types>timestamp\ with\ time\ zone</types>
                    </forcedType>
                </forcedTypes>

                <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                <includes>author</includes>
                <excludes/>
                <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
            </database>
            <target>
                <packageName>xxx.table</packageName>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
            </target>
        </generator>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, it is quite unintuitive: the manual only mentions "Java regex". Thanks anyway for the nice digging!

Comment: @assylias You're welcome.  That aspect of the configuration is definitely unintuitive and inadequately documented.  I got the answer by a little trial and error and then dug up the explanation as to why after the fact.

Comment: That's very unfortunate indeed, and shouldn't be necessary. Fix on the way (hopefully): https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4691

Comment: @LukasEder During my digging, I came across the GitHub issue for why the `COMMENTS` flag was introduced.  I noted it in the new issue that you just created.

Answer (score 4):

Jooq 3.11 seems to turn a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` into an `OffsetDateTime` when `javaTimeTypes` is enabled, and it also complains about `customTypes` being deprecated, so I wasn't able to get the other answers to work for me.

Here's how I was able to get this to work, using the gradle jooq plugin:

```
// inside the jooq...generator.database of build.gradle:
forcedTypes {
    forcedType {
        userType = 'java.time.Instant'
        converter = '''
        org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(
            java.time.OffsetDateTime.class,
            java.time.Instant.class,
            o -> o.toInstant(),
            i -> i.atOffset(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC))
        '''
        types = 'timestamp\\ with\\ time\\ zone'
    }
}
```

It should be pretty easy to turn this into XML for Maven or manual invocation of the code generator, as the gradle plugin's parameters exactly match the structure of the XML. Note that Groovy syntax requires the doubling of the backslashes in the `types` pattern, so that would need to be adjusted if converting to XML.

This uses an inline converter to turn the `OffsetDateTime` that Jooq currently uses into an `Instant`. No external converter class is necessary.